# How to Change Separators of org-tag in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

I'm a light user who use `org-mode` since 6 month ago. I think It's super useful mode to make GTD schedule and write a simple note.

but when I use `org-mode` I couldn't find the delimiters of tag except for `:` like `:TAG:`

what I want is changing delimiters of `org-tag` like `TAG1|TAG2|` or `#TAG1#TAG2#` ...

anyone how to do this?

Comment: The `:` format seems to be hard-coded (look at file `org.el`).

Comment: Maybe you can try to modify only the display effect like [org-bullets](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/org-bullets), if that's acceptable and possible.

Comment: can org-bullets change the shape of tag separator? @xuchunyang I already used it for change the shape of *, ** to bullets

Comment: @JeanPierre That's too bad :-/ .. why they wrote codes like this? Thank you for the reply anyway

Comment: @edward0im it can't. I meant looking at the code of org-bullets to get inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not customizable without forking the code repo.

According to the manual : 
https://orgmode.org/manual/Tags.html, **Tags must be preceded and followed by a single colon**

Incase you are looking to modify the org source code, good starting point would be
https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/org.el#L567

variables org-tag-re, org-tag-group-re, org-tag-line-re is where the regex for TAGS are declared in which colon is hard coded. These variables are declared using defconst (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Variables.html) and so the variables cant be customized.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :-) I'll try it out soon